# How to add two conditions in laravel relationship?

Tags: laravel

I have a `post`, `group`, `user` and `group_user` table. The post table has `user_id` and `group_id` foreign key, and `group_user` also has `user_id` and `group_id` foreign key.

In post-relationship, I want `group_user` details of the `post` with same `user_id` and `group`. But I can't find a better way. Is there a way where I can put two conditions in the relation table ?

Comment: have you try anything??

Answer (score 0):

After few attempts with laravel `hasonethrough` relationship, i added the following method. But it does not work. I need second condition for `user_id` as well.

in post class

```
public function groupUser()
     {
         return $this->hasManyThrough( 'App\Models\User','App\Models\GroupUser','group_id','id','group_id','user_id')->select('group_user.*');
     }
```

If there are more users in the group, it shows multiple users. I need only user who has created post.

I have kept `hasManyThrough` purposefully to check only one result should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I created a custom class and overwrite addEagerConstraints method. It worked. Thanks

```
public function addEagerConstraints(array $models)
{
    $whereIn = $this->whereInMethod($this->farParent, $this->localKey);

    $this->query->{$whereIn}(
        $this->getQualifiedFirstKeyName(), $this->getKeys($models, $this->localKey)
    );
     $this->query->{$whereIn}(
        $this->getQualifiedFarKeyName(), $this->getKeys($models, $this->secondLocalKey)
    );
}
```